# What should I do when I'm on a shortlist for a postdoc?

Tags: postdocs, job-search, job

I was notified via a backchannel that I'm on a shortlist for a competitive top tier postdoc in my STEM field, though some offers were already made. There's no interview process, but is there anything I can do to tip the odds in my favor?

Comment: "Publish more" might work, but presumably you already do that.

Comment: Don't do anything obnoxious on the internet

Comment: Hype up your competition so they get better offers?

Answer (score 13):

No. You just have to wait and let the process take its course.

Answer (score 2):

Don't ever tell anyone you have backchannel knowledge. If you seek advantage with it, it is unethical and may (or will) even count against you. Any backchannel is capable of two-way communication, making it a possible means of lobbying, influencing, negotiating and, at its worst, things such as bribery. In such ways the person could be suspected of seeking or obtaining advantage.

If you get the post and tell, you run the risk that you will be seen as having had unfair advantage. Forget about it; someone was just trying to make you feel good but it is not a key to any action

Comment: I do not understand what sort of advantage could be obtained.

Comment: Your comment is much clearer than your answer.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I take your point and have moved my comment to the accordingly edited answer. Thanks for the stimulus.